# Want to show navigation bar while opening URL-iPhone

Tags: iphone, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have been scratching my head for this issue. I hope the query title is self explanatory. On clicking a button i am opening URL like following:

NSURL *girlsUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_URL_GIRLS objectAtIndex:(indexValue*3 + currentPageNumber)]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:girlsUrl];

its opening a URL in same view but navigation bar is set as default hidden. i want to add an option of navigating back at top, to application after seeing URL

Regards,

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the URL with the UIApplication, you may instead want to consider implementing a UIWebView - download the data at the URL yourself, then display it in a web view and add that view (and a view controller) to a navigation controller. That way, you get the Back button and the system bar at the top, while still displaying the URL  you want.